# Import external sass or scss variables with Svelte and Vite

Tags: sass, svelte, vite

I've created a big sass stylesheet with all sorts of colors. Following [vite's guide for sass](https://vitejs.dev/guide/features.html#css-pre-processors), I got sass working in my components. Now I'd like to use these external variables in my Svelte components' stylesheets as well.

So far I've tried:

```
@use "./test.sass" // along with "./test"
p {
  color: $testColor
}
```

As well as

```
@import url("./test.sass") // along with "./test"
// ... same as above
```

It gives me an error `Error: Undefined variable`. And my variable is defined properly in test.sass

Answer (score 3):

`@use` wraps imported variables in a namespace, so instead of `$testColor` you have to explicitly state that these variables come from a module.

```
@use "./test.sass"
p {
  color: test.$testColor
}
```

or

```
@use "./test.sass" as *
p {
 color: $testColor
}
```